# MongoDB querying time is too slow via pymongo.How can I improve the speed of querying?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

We have mongo server with 10GB cluster size with documents around 300k. When using the following code:

```
curs = collection.find({"cust_id":1, "course":"D123"})
df=  pd.DataFrame(list(curs))
```

it takes huge time like around 2 minutes which results 2 documents. Is it normal ?? How can I improve the querying speed ? Most of the time I query for two keys iteratively as I have multi index search with 2 indices in python (dataframe)

Comment: Is your MongoDB instance local?

Comment: You aren't applying a filter, so your collection only has 2 documents? If this is the case then no, it's not normal.

Comment: @FluxedScript no its cloud instance

Comment: Try running a local instance @Vas you could install the docker desktop and run it there for it